# .net: adding a new source to Paket config

Tags: .net-core, f#, nuget, paket

Background: I experienced what appeared to be a bug in [`System.CommandLine`](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api) and noticed the Nuget package that I used ([`System.CommandLine.Experimental 0.3.0-alpha.19405.1`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.CommandLine.Experimental)) hadn't been updated for 3 months. I felt I should try out a nightly build before I file a bug report.

Then I followed their README which stated

> Daily builds are available if you add this feed to your nuget.config: https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet-core/index.json.

and as I was using Paket for my toy project (primarily for learning purposes) that needed `System.CommandLine`, I instead updated `packet.dependencies`

```
source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
nuget FSharp.Core
source https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet-core/index.json
nuget System.CommandLine.Experimental
```

However when I ran `paket update`

```
$ paket update
Paket version 5.224.0                          
Resolving packages for group Main:
Possible Performance degradation, could not retrieve 'https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet-core/index.json/Packages?semVerLevel=2.0.0&$filter=Id eq 'System.CommandLine.Experimental'', ignoring further warnings for this source
 - FSharp.Core 4.7.0
 - System.CommandLine.Experimental 0.3.0-alpha.19405.1
 - system.memory 4.5.3
 - Microsoft.CSharp 4.6.0
 - System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.6.0
 - System.Buffers 4.5.0
 - System.Numerics.Vectors 4.5.0
/home/nodakai/prog/CommandLineFSharp/paket.lock is already up-to-date
...snip...
```

And all I got was a 3-months old version from Nuget `0.3.0-alpha.19405.1` which made me sad.

What did I do wrong?

FWIW when I opened the source URL https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet-core/index.json with my web browser, it didn't seem to directly refer to `System.CommandLine`. But I'm not familiar with Nuget and/or Paket ecosystem so I'm not sure if there was anything wrong with the source data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `prerelease` in `paket.dependencies` i.e.:

`nuget System.CommandLine.Experimental prerelease`

The available versions are listed here:

https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet-core/flatcontainer/system.commandline.experimental/index.json

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me. Got the same `System.CommandLine.Experimental (0.3.0-alpha.19405.1)` in `paket.lock`